# What does "1200 dpi at 1 bit" mean? Save plot with ggsave in R at 1 bit

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, resolution, bit

I have a question about image resolution, as it's not an area with which I'm particularly familiar.

I'm saving a black and white (actually, grayscale) plot I created with `ggplot()` (`ggplot2` package) in R using `ggsave()`. According to a journal's specifications, "Line art (black and white) should be scanned at 1200 dpi at 1 bit." I've specified DPI in the past, but I don't understand the "1 bit" portion (contrast this with their request for color images to be "300 dpi at 8 bit", e.g.).

What option do I use in `ggsave()` to ensure 1 bit (or 8 bit, e.g.)? Also, a brief explanation of a "bit" in this context (at a novice level) would be appreciated.

Currently, my code reads:

```
ggsave("Fig01.tiff", device="tiff", width=5, dpi=1200)
```

I can provide a minimal working example leading up to the above `ggsave()` command if needed, but I don't believe it's necessary to answer the question.

Comment: One bit means just two colours: pure black or pure white, no grays.  The R devices don't support this specifically, though `antialias="none"` with just `"black"` as a colour on a white background should allow conversion to it.

Comment: Hmmm...okay, so according to this journal, anything with tones of gray would be considered "colored" (and thus should be at 8 bit), not black and white, since they say "Line art (black and white)...at 1200 dpi at 1 bit", which only allows pure black and pure white?

Comment: Ah ha, just answered my own question (don't know how I missed this - I guess I've always lumped black and white and grayscale together, but obviously shouldn't!). It actually says, "Color **and grayscale** images should be scanned at 300 dpi at 8 bit." At least I learned something! Thank you!

Comment: As a follow-up, do you know how to specify 8 bit for output from `ggsave`, or is 8 bit the default for color/grayscale images?

Comment: Generally I don't think R allows you to pick bit depth.  It likely uses 8 bit colour for everything.  Programs like ImageMagick can convert files to specific formats.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think I'll just specify 300 dpi and go with it. Thanks again!

Comment: @user2554330 If you'd like to write up a summary based on these comments as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"One bit" means just two colours: pure black or pure white, no grays. The R devices don't support this specifically, though antialias="none" with just "black" as a colour on a white background will likely result in a just black and white pixels.

However, I don't think R allows you to pick bit depth. It likely uses 8 bit colour for everything. Programs like ImageMagick can convert files to specific formats.  The `magick` package in R gives access to the ImageMagick functions, but I don't know what the commands would be to rewrite an image in black and white.

Comment: Although I said this comment in the original posting, it might be helpful for people to see it here: My issue was actually in misunderstanding true black and white (ONLY black and ONLY white), as opposed to grayscale. The journal considers grayscale "colored", which requires 8 bits, not 1. This makes things much clearer! Thanks again, @user2554330!